# PHP 5.3 to 7.3 upgrade failed

Tags: php, nginx, centos6

I was trying to upgrade a client's server running CentOS 6, PHP 5.3.29 (I know, RIGHT??) with nginx 1.10.3.
So I installed everything like usual using:

```
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-6.rpm epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
```

and the commands to upgrade and enable php 7.3 `yum-config-manager --enable remi-php73`
but it only shows:

```
=============================== repo: remi-php73 ===============================
[remi-php73]
bandwidth = 0
base_persistdir = /var/lib/yum/repos/i386/6
baseurl =
cache = 0
cachedir = /var/cache/yum/i386/6/remi-php73
cost = 1000
enabled = True
enablegroups = True
exclude =
failovermethod = priority
ftp_disable_epsv = False
gpgcadir = /var/lib/yum/repos/i386/6/remi-php73/gpgcadir
gpgcakey =
gpgcheck = True
gpgdir = /var/lib/yum/repos/i386/6/remi-php73/gpgdir
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
hdrdir = /var/cache/yum/i386/6/remi-php73/headers
http_caching = all
includepkgs =
keepalive = True
mdpolicy = group:primary
mediaid =
metadata_expire = 21600
metalink =
mirrorlist = http://cdn.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/php73/mirror
mirrorlist_expire = 86400
name = Remi's PHP 7.3 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 6 - i386
old_base_cache_dir =
password =
persistdir = /var/lib/yum/repos/i386/6/remi-php73
pkgdir = /var/cache/yum/i386/6/remi-php73/packages
proxy = False
proxy_dict =
proxy_password =
proxy_username =
repo_gpgcheck = False
retries = 10
skip_if_unavailable = False
ssl_check_cert_permissions = True
sslcacert =
sslclientcert =
sslclientkey =
sslverify = True
throttle = 0
timeout = 30.0
username =
```

I searched for a while and ended up finding similar problem here: [How to install PHP 7.3 on Linux version 3.10.0 kbuilder.dev.centos.org) (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59892605/how-to-install-php-7-3-on-linux-version-3-10-0-kbuilder-dev-centos-org-red-hat)
but it wasn't totally the same problem. or is it?
Is it only due to mysql and other dependencies or do I need to do something else?
I also don't want to break the site since it's a huge project with almost a million visitors daily.
Please point me the direction or a working solution without messing things up. thank you
Curent PHP dependencies:

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
memcache
mhash
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
SQLite
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
uploadprogress
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

Answer (score 0):

> yum-config-manager --enable remi-php73 but it only shows:

No issue there, this is the default behavior of "yum-config-manager" (display the new content of the repo file).

After enabling the repository, you can run the upgrade

```
yum update
```

As explained by the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

**WARNING**: CentOS 6 will reach its end of life at the end of the month... in 10 days, so it is really urgent to upgrade your server to CentOS 7 or CentOS 8.

Comment: Did that, but what I get is:

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.earthlink.iq
 * remi: mirror.23media.com
 * remi-php73: mirror.23media.com
 * remi-safe: mirror.23media.com
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
No Packages marked for Update

Comment: Not enough information (enabled repositories, installed packages, yum plugins...) full yum output may help.

Comment: Long list so I had to upload them to a text file. here's is my "yum list installed" output. https://file.io/TkBSaFwTFehq
and this is "rpm -qa" file. https://file.io/jdTams41GFw2 
and this is  "yum repolist enabled" : https://file.io/d1Gx7cbfS5et

Comment: According to installed RPM list, you are running 7.3.24 (which is already the lastest version, so nothing to update is expected)

Comment: exactly. but when I run php -v it's still on 5.3.

Comment: "which php"  and "/usr/bin/php -v"

Comment: "which php" : /usr/local/bin/php
and "/usr/bin/php -v" : PHP 7.3.24 (cli) (built: Oct 27 2020 12:24:50)

Comment: So you have your answer, you are using a "build from sources" version installed in /usr/local, simply remove it.

Comment: thank you so much @remi-collet 
just to make sure I got it correctly. I should "yum remove [package name]" which is php 5.3. right?

Comment: yum allow to remove "packages" not something build manually, you have to delete these files

Comment: so I just remove " /usr/local/bin/php" ? after that what should be done? sorry if this is a dumb question, but I haven't done this one

Comment: /usr/bin/php will be find and used as the default version

Comment: I think there might be a problem with that, because after I removed /usr/local/bin/php, when I use php -v, it says "bash usr/local/bin/php: no such file or directory". @remi-collet

Comment: " rm -rf /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/lib/php " would this work?